# What is the first usage of the word "doobie" in OED?

Tags: etymology

It is almost impossible to get a clear answer to this question in the US online.  For example:  Ted and Fay were smoking a doobie to clear their heads before going out.

Comment: I didn't notice and I don't know why this question is tagged "single-word-request" but the older question mentions the OED and provides 1967 as the earliest instance in print.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ...not convinced. The William's citation seems to be describing a well-established usage.

Comment: @Cascabel You may not be convinced but it's got to be proved. If there is an earlier instance than 1967, the answer should be posted on FF's question, which showed considerable research: an OED citation, Ngram link, and Yahoo! answers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA When I say that I am unconvinced it is because I heard it before 1967 while still in high school in up-state New York, not exactly a bastion of black culture.

Comment: It should be closed as a duplicate.  I was aware of the earlier answer, but couldn't find it in English Language, certainly due to operator error on my part.  Mari-LouA found the earlier query.  Thank you.